# Subtract rows which are grouped in power bI

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I am working on Power BI and have appended the data. Once appended i have grouped data between "R" (revenue) and "C" (cost). Now i want to reduce "R"-"C" in power BI. Can you help me

Comment: show us sample data and desired result, it will be helpful to give some ideas

Comment: DateId ItemType USD Customer
201811 R 100 XX
201811 R 200 YY
201811 R 300 ZZ
201811 C 40 XX
201811 C 80 YY
201811 C 200 ZZ
This is a sample data wherein "R" and "C" are in same column and i need to subtract the same.